# How to send user data to a new activity using Facebook Login?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, facebook-android-sdk

I've been working in an app which uses Facebook login to identify a user. Right now, i've added the login successfully, but I need to get some user information (like name and age) and send it to a new activity. I've been searching how to do it and I've only found how to do each one of these by themselves, and when  I try to do both the app crashes.
This is my current onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);

    facebookButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
    facebookButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, user_birthday"));

    facebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            info.setText(getString(R.string.facebook_login_cancel));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            info.setText(getString(R.string.facebook_login_fail));
        }
    });
}
```

So now, my question is how do I "give" the created bundle to start a new Activity and how do I access this data. I've tried doing it the "normal" way, even without the bundle, with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, BlankActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And the app crashes everytime after I login.

How can I do this then?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the OnSuccess method instead of Bundle paraneters...

```
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    }
                });

         Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, RecievingActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("keyName", value);  
         startActivity(intent);

    }
```

and retrieve the information in Activity B like that:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName","defaultKey");
```

Comment: I know how to give extras to a new activity, the problem is when these extras are user info, I haven't found out how to get the user data I need from Facebook and giving it to the new activity.

Comment: @Cristian you wanted to get User data from response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LoginManager. Call click event for Facebook login.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_friends", "user_posts");
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

    }

Then add this function:

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    JSONObject me = response.getJSONObject();
                                    try {
                                        if (me != null) {
                                            User userObj = new UserData().GetFBUserData(object);

                                                String text = me.getString("email");
                                            Log.d("email", text);
                                            String email = object.optString("email");
                                            String id = object.optString("id");
                                            String name = object.optString("name");
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    String REQUEST_FIELDS =
                            TextUtils.join(",", new String[]{"id", "name", "link", "email", "picture", "gender", "birthday","friendlists{id}","friends"});
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", REQUEST_FIELDS);
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                   GraphRequest.executeBatchAsync(request);

                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                //mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));
            }
    }
```

This code is working. I implement this code. This code will return user profile such as name, email, image. You can call new activity from inside onCompleted function.